# PC RasterTools plug in not installed

Tags: qgis, raster, toolbox

I had to force a close on QGIS 3.10 recently. Since then, I've had recurring message 'PC Raster Toolbox not installed' continually. Reinstalling the Toolbox makes no difference. I've uninstalled QGIS and upgraded to 3.16 Hannover but I'm still getting the issue, and functionality is lost as a result.

Any idea how I fix this?

Comment: Why don't try to make a clean new installation, let' say of verision QGIS 3.22.2?

Comment: Thanks Erick. That might be the route to go.